# What's the name of jQuery plugin which auto arranges div/image elements on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

That plugin was able to arrange elements to remove empty spaces between them.

Example:

[image: http://imgur.com/pUR0Z.jpg]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Masonry, if I'm not mistaken. Here's an url: http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/

Cheers.

Comment: you can also look into isotope. It has more options and masonry is included in it.

Comment: it's better than masonry even.